# bit-field parsing incorrect in visual studio 2015 (c++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, bit-fields

I have created this struct (my cpp compiler is the default visual studio 2015 compiler):

```
struct MyStruct
{
    unsigned short length : 9;
    unsigned short flag : 1;
    unsigned short opcode : 6;
};
```

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe.aspx) official documentation, bit fields are represented low to high bit, and in my case no padding will be added since the underlying type fits exactly to the bit-field members.

I use this struct in the following function (assume SomeClass knows about MyStruct):

```
void SomeClass::receiveData(void * pData)
{
    unsigned short* test = static_cast<unsigned short*>(pData);
    MyStruct* myHeader = static_cast<MyStruct*>(pData)
}
```

Please assume i am not allowed to change receiveData's signature.
Now, evidently when test is equal to:

```
0x0a08
```

then myHeader contains:

```
length: 0xa
flag:   0x0
opcode: 0x2
```

Why is flag not equal to 1 and why is length not equal to 8? the binary representation of 0x0a08 is supposed to fit a myHeader containing:

```
length: 0x8
flag:   0x1
opcode: 0x2
```

Comment: Is it legal to reinterpret such a class like that? I don't recall it being allowed for anything other than a `char*` (or is it `unsigned char*`?)

Comment: That should break strict aliasing. And the result would very much depend on things like [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: _"**the** binary representation of 0x0a08"_ I like how you think that there is only one :)

Comment: GCC doesn't even accept those casts (and did you mean `test`, not `pData`, on `receiveData`'s second line?) — but when I fix that, [I get the results you expected](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b27503aa67a511e6). It could be you're coming up against the consequences of such a violent strict aliasing violation, or it could be that MSVS works differently somehow, or it could be you've misreported something as well as the problems listed above. Please present your [MCVE].

Comment: Yes, I have accidentally misreported the expected results. but i did not mean "test" on receiveData's second line. as can be seen [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e3cc6032471fd23). the purpose of test was to exhibit the unexpected result.

Comment: Strict aliasing was indeed the problem (I was not familiar with this issue). The cast is allowed by the MSVS compiler, but it renders the result prone to endianness issues like @Someprogrammerdude pointed out. If you post an answer i will accept.

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation will work for the most part. A `typedef` helps keep the syntax to a minimum. Essentially, you just need the single reinterpret case for `myHeader` to the address of `pData`. With that done, your code provides the expected output, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct MyStruct {
    unsigned short length : 9;
    unsigned short flag   : 1;
    unsigned short opcode : 6;
} mystruct_t;

int main (void)
{
    unsigned short pData  = { 0x0a08 };
    mystruct_t* myHeader = reinterpret_cast<mystruct_t*>((void*)&pData);

    std::cout << myHeader->length << '\n';
    std::cout << myHeader->flag << '\n';
    std::cout << myHeader->opcode << '\n';
}
```

**VS-15 Compiler String**

```
> cl /nologo /Wall /wd4514 /wd4530 /wd4710 /wd4820 /wd4996 /wd4986 /Ox 
/Foobj/bitfield_struct /Febin/bitfield_struct /Tp bitfield_struct.cpp
```

**Example Use/Output VS 15**

```
c:\Users\david\Documents\dev\src-cpp\tmp>bin\bitfield_struct.exe
8
1
2
```

**Example Use/Output (gcc)**

```
$ ./bin/bitfield_struct
8
1
2
```

If that isn't what you were trying to achieve, let me know and I'm happy to help further.

Comment: This does indeed work, but the underlying concept is that endianness will affect the result. In my particular case, the message is sent from a little endian architecture, but proccessed on a big endian one, so that totally messed up my parsing. I know i failed to mention this, but still the answer does not help understand this issue (see comments on question).

Comment: `htons` and `ntohs` are useful